# How to avoid obstacles in missions?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

i am currently testing the missions part of the sdk (with pc simulator) and when i am running missions it seems to be going straightforward ignoring obstacles (the obstacle is coming from the real camera of the drone).
I've also turned on 2 properties that i thought will work but it seems that it doesn't:
`setCollisionAvoidanceEnabled` + `setActiveObstacleAvoidanceEnabled` both to true.
Is there another option or property that needs to be set to true that i am missing?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When using the MobileSDK and missions, you are simply pushing onto the flight controller what you would like the mission to be. Which means, that the execution of it is done on the flight controller.

This is also true for the obstacle avoidance and unfortunately, missions on most aircraft doesn't use obstacle avoidance at the same time regardless of you calling `setCollisionAvoidanceEnabled`.

There are ways to achieve these results using an OnboardSDK enabled aircraft (M100, M210+, M600 or N3/A3 based platform) and either the sensor package on board (M210 with front sensors) or add your sensors (Stereo cams, lidar 1D/2D/3D) and have a routine that runs in parallel to have both missions and obstacle avoidance a the same time.

Of course this is more complex, but if you're interested let me know.

Comment: But isn't there some global callback for obstacles that inside this callback i can call `pauseTimeline`? And in this way to build some safe obstacle system?

Comment: The timeline is a linear system today. For obstacle avoidance during a mission, you would need a parallel system. :-/

Comment: But can i create this system on my own?
For example in the callback of the obstacle, pause the timeline? Is it something that can work? Or while in the missions system the obstacle callback won't work at all?

Comment: You can create a system of your own, but it can't be run from the mobile side unfortunately. The APIs we provide don't give you raw access to the sensor package or low level commands to the flight controller.

Comment: So basically if there will be a wall between 2 waypoints, the drone will crush into the wall?

Answer (score 1):

When using the simulation the is no avoidance active,  the setting is ignored.   Only when flying for real does the avoidance systems activate.   You can't trick the system by placing things in front of the aircraft.

You will notice the same is true when stimulating flight, the aircraft reports distance to an obstacle but does not stop.